# error: (-210:Unsupported format or combination of formats) Video source is not supported by hardware video decoder in function 'create'

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu-18.04, nvidia

### My Environment info:

- Operating system: Ubuntu 18.04
- OpenCV: 4.3.0
- CUDA: 10.2
- NVIDIA gpu: GEFORCE RTX 2060

My cmake list before install opencv:

> cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE 
> -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local 
> -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON 
> -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=OFF 
> -D WITH_TBB=ON \      -D WITH_CUDA=ON 
> -D CUDA_GENERATION=Turing \   -D BUILD_opencv_cudacodec=ON 
> -D ENABLE_FAST_MATH=ON 
> -D NVCUVID_FAST_MATH=ON 
> -D CUDA_FAST_MATH=ON 
> -D WITH_CUBLAS=ON 
> -D BUILD_opencv_java=OFF 
> -D BUILD_ZLIB=ON 
> -D BUILD_TIFF=ON 
> -D WITH_GTK=ON 
> -D WITH_NVCUVID=ON 
> -D WITH_FFMPEG=ON 
> -D CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local/cuda-10.2 
> -D WITH_1394=ON 
> -D CUDNN_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/cuda/include 
> -D CUDNN_LIBRARY=/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn.so.7.6.5 
> -D OPENCV_GENERATE_PKGCONFIG=ON 
> -D OPENCV_PC_FILE_NAME=opencv4.pc 
> -D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON 
> -D WITH_GSTREAMER=ON 
> -D WITH_V4L=ON 
> -D OPENCV_PYTHON3_INSTALL_PATH=$cwd/OpenCV-4.3.0-py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages
>
> -D WITH_QT=ON 
> -D WITH_CUDNN=ON 
> -D OPENCV_DNN_CUDA=ON 
> -D WITH_OPENGL=ON 
> -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../../opencv_contrib/modules 
> -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..

After Cmake a part of output:

```
. .
--   Video I/O:
--     DC1394:                      YES (2.2.5)
--     FFMPEG:                      YES
--       avcodec:                   YES (57.107.100)
--       avformat:                  YES (57.83.100)
--       avutil:                    YES (55.78.100)
--       swscale:                   YES (4.8.100)
--       avresample:                YES (3.7.0)
--     GStreamer:                   YES (1.14.5)
--     v4l/v4l2:                    YES (linux/videodev2.h)
-- 
--   Parallel framework:            TBB (ver 2017.0 interface 9107)
-- 
--   Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)
-- 
--   Other third-party libraries:
--     Intel IPP:                   2020.0.0 Gold [2020.0.0]
--            at:                   /home/yongatek02/opencv/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/icv
--     Intel IPP IW:                sources (2020.0.0)
--               at:                /home/yongatek02/opencv/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/iw
--     Lapack:                      NO
--     Eigen:                       YES (ver 3.3.4)
--     Custom HAL:                  NO
--     Protobuf:                    build (3.5.1)
-- 
--   NVIDIA CUDA:                   YES (ver 10.2, CUFFT CUBLAS NVCUVID FAST_MATH)
--     NVIDIA GPU arch:             75
--     NVIDIA PTX archs:
-- 
--   cuDNN:                         YES (ver 7.6.5)
-- 
--   OpenCL:                        YES (no extra features)
--     Include path:                /home/yongatek02/opencv/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
--     Link libraries:              Dynamic load . .
```

I tested simple cuda examples and OpenCV and working fine no problem. I tried [this example](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/gpu/video_reader.cpp) to be able to decode my IP camera stream with GPU. It compiled fine with this command via on terminal:

```
g++ -std=c++11 codec.cpp `pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv4` -o output
```

Here is also my code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv_modules.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/cudacodec.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    const std::string fname = "rtsp://usrname/ipadress..."; // Tried also different formats of videos such as YUV,mp4 webM

    cv::namedWindow("GPU", cv::WINDOW_NORMAL);

    cv::cuda::GpuMat d_frame;
    cv::Ptr<cv::cudacodec::VideoReader> d_reader = cv::cudacodec::createVideoReader(fname);

    for (;;)
    {

        if (!d_reader->nextFrame(d_frame))
            break;

        cv::Mat frame;
        d_frame.download(frame);
        cv::imshow("GPU", frame);

        if (cv::waitKey(3) > 0)
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But when I tried to run it, it gives me this error:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
> what():  OpenCV(4.3.0)
> /home/yongatek02/opencv_contrib/modules/cudacodec/src/video_decoder.cpp:101:
> error: (-210:Unsupported format or combination of formats) Video
> source is not supported by hardware video decoder in function 'create'
>
> Aborted (core dumped)

I also tried to use some different types of formats such as YUV, MP4, webm etc. and the error is still the same.

**What I am missing here ?**

Comment: are you able to read the stream from RTSP without CUDA ?

Comment: @farbiondriven I am able to read by VideoCapture or VLC, I can read stream and display also.

Comment: @talonmies Why do you think that there is no relation with cuda in my question?

Comment: Ok so everything is fine with the stream itself. My question was more: Could you read the stream using opencv itself but NO cuda ? I think indeed the issue is on binding the stream to the CUDA reader.

Comment: @farbiondriven I can use some example with opencv functions such as ```cv::cuda::findcontours...```.  This means cuda installed properly. Yes, no cuda because no option to read by videocapture via on cuda. The only way is with createVideoReader but it also fails. I dont know where is the mistake. I also installed NVIDIA Video Codec SDK to be able to use NVCUVID. but still fails..

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk: Because what you are using isn't part of CUDA it is part of OpenCV and you state "...tested simple cuda examples and OpenCV and working fine no problem", so your underlying CUDA infrastructure works. There is nothing related to *CUDA programming* in your question  -- the "cudacodec" uses FFMPEG to access video, which in turn uses the NVIDIA video decoder hardware and SDK which have nothing to do with CUDA. That's why

Comment: Sir I have the same problem, did you solve it ? Could you please share the solution?

Comment: @NaserPiltan yeah I actually solved it before, [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CBMjBKwVaUk) is my demo also. i just installed cuda opencv and run it, it worked. I do not actually remember what I did, and why i got this error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I was processing video files on local disk. It turned out that the cudacodec did not support the codec of its audio track. I used ffmpeg to drop the audio track and it worked properly.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -an output.mp4
```